# Close a question glitch

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I do not have the reputation required to be allowed the privilege of closing a question.
But I am allowed to close only my own questions.

See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT8Fo.png) screenshot and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc793.png) as well.

Now this might seem silly but it actually is a glitch and needs to be removed.

1. Why would I close my own question?
2. Some of my answered questions although marked with an accepted answer are not closed.
3. I can understand that maybe a user might want to close a question if the user is satisfied with just the comments for AmiRite type questions. But when I click on 'close' under my question, I get the options that seem not useful at all.

P.S - If they want to let me use the privilege then let me use it on everyone. I don't mind :P

Comment: get to 3k rep, i'll see you there ;D You can get there in less than 3 months, from personal experience

Comment: Well, you can delete own posts, and quite a bit of people does that sometimes. When q. is answered, then it's not possible, but closing still is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your questions you seem to have a misconception as to the purpose of closing a question. Please read [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) first, then come back to this.

> 1. Why would I close my own question?

I imagine this is a rare scenario, but it is sometimes used, e.g. when the asker finds a duplicate of their own question after asking it. The asker does not then need to wait for 5 other people to close the question as a duplicate. Alternatively, the asker may come to the realisation that their question is not appropriate for SE. Of course, this requires some humility on the part of the asker to acknowledge that their question is "worthy" of closure.

> 2. Some of my answered questions although marked with an accepted answer are not closed.
> 3. I can understand that maybe a user might want to close a question if the user is satisfied with just the comments for AmiRite type questions. But when I click on 'close' under my question, I get the options that seem not useful at all.

The purpose of closure is not to mark a question as being "solved". The accept tick / check mark serves that purpose. Closure is for questions that should not be asked here in the first place, cf. the link above.